# sum of values in array returns memory address unless sizeof(array)/2

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

Here is the program I'm working on, it's simple but helps me to figure out the basics of C++. I'm struggling with pointers and try to understand how it works.

```
    int main()
            {

                unsigned int note;
                unsigned int nombreDeNotesASaisir = 0;
                unsigned int totalDesNotes = 0;

cin >> nombreDeNotesASaisir;

                int* tableauDeNotes = new int[nombreDeNotesASaisir] {};

        for (int i = 0; i < nombreDeNotesASaisir; i++)
            {
                cin >> note;
                tableauDeNotes[i] = note;
            }

                // method that is supposed to make the sum of all the values inside the array 

                for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tableauDeNotes); i++)
                {
                    totalDesNotes += *(tableauDeNotes + i);
                }

                cout << "le total des notes est de :" << totalDesNotes << "\n";

                //print the average of all the marks

                unsigned int moyenne = totalDesNotes / nombreDeNotesASaisir;
                cout << moyenne << ' ';


                return 0;
            }
```

I cant seem to get the result of the operation, instead i think i get the memory address, why is that and what can I do to get it working ?

PS: the weird thing is that when i divide the sizeof(array)/2 it returns the correct sum of the values

Comment: You do `new int[0]`...

Comment: Also, `sizeof(tableauDeNotes)` evaluates to the size of a pointer, not the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator "sizeof" does not return the number of elements in the array.
Instead it returns the size of the passed variable.

In your case the passed variable is a **pointer** not an array!
Size of a pointer is 4 bytes on 32 bit architectures, and 8 bytes on 64 bit architectures. So sizeof(tableauDeNotes) returns 4 or 8.

If you had a variable like this:

```
int myTable[5];
```

Then this would be an **array**. sizeof(myTable) would return total size of myTable, which is:

```
sizeof(myTable) = 5 * sizeof(int)
```

So depending on the architecture it will be for 32 bit ints:
5 * 4 = 20
or for 64 bit ints:
5 * 8 = 40.

If you would like to get number of elements in myTable, you could use this:

```
int numElements = sizeof(myTable) / sizeof(int);
```

But it works for **tables** only, not for **pointers** as in your case.

In your case you should just use nombreDeNotesASaisir instead of sizeof operator.